# Pandoc gives "undefined control sequence" error for seemingly valid statement

Tags: amsmath, pandoc

I am trying to compile

```
$\forall u, v, w \in \R^m and c, d \in \R$
```

All of these are valid symbols and there is no problem in the syntax, as far as I know. However, pandoc refuses to compile it and says there is an undefined control sequence, citing `\(\forall u, v, w \in \R`. I don't know why that first `\(` is there because in my text file it is a `$`. What is wrong with this snippet?

NB: it is 100% this snippet that is the problem since the error persisted after I put it in another file all on its own and tried to compile it.

Edit: this is the entire file. If I put that snippet into its own file it gives the exact same error so I do not see why posting my entire file is necessary. The **full** error message is as follows (yes, it does say l.61 even though my document is 1 line long):
[image]

Comment: in view of your NB you should instead post the test file that you created, so people can debug.

Comment: `\R` is not defined by default, have you defined it?

Comment: Is `\R` defined? The last token in the error message is the one were TeX stopped; this seems to be `\R` if you quoted the message correctly.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  just a guess ... `\R` isn't a "basic" command; it's often defined to be `\mathbb{R}`, but that definition has to be provided.

Comment: Could you post the (complete) mardown file that replicates your problem?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle @gernot `\R` is definitely defined, and it works in other parts of my document.

Comment: The image of the error message clearly shows `\R` is not defined and the expression containing `\R` is not the one you have in your question which does not have `\(` or `a_i`

Comment: clearly the snippet is not the entire file as you state since you posted a one line snippet and the error is on line 61 and shows different text.

Comment: please post the latex file that pandoc generated and passed to latex, not your initial pandoc input.

Answer (score 2):

The format for the error message is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 $\forall u, v, w \in \R
                           ^m and c, d \in \R$
? h
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

the linebreak is important as that pinpoints exactly where TeX generated
the error.

So here `\R` is the undefined command. You could define it to be `\mathbb{R}` or `\mathbf{R}` or whatever you need.

complete test file:

```
$\forall u, v, w \in \R^m and c, d \in \R$

\bye
```

Comment: No, `\R` is definitely defined here and works on its own.

Comment: @Bluefire see above where I have added a complete test file. You have neither shown your full input, nor shown the error message that you got, so the assumption has to be that R is not defined or the error is generated by some different code. Please fix your question to show an a test file.

Comment: I have posted an update to the question.